# Better way to handle errors with Monix Observable

Tags: scala, observable, monix

I am trying to build reactive application with monix 3.0.0-RC1.

For instance a have a Seq of Int's, and the second element is wrong. I can use `Oservable.raiseError(...)` to handle this:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1,2,3))
    .flatMap( i =>
      if (i == 2) Observable.raiseError(new Exception("Wrong i"))
      else Observable.pure(i)
    )
    .doOnNext(i => println(s"Processing $i"))
    .foreachL(i => println(s"Finished $i"))
    .onErrorHandle(_ => Task.unit)
```

I do not like thrown exception in the code above.

In the other hand I can use Scala's `Either`:

```
Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1,2,3))
  .map( i =>
    if (i == 2) Left("Wrong i")
    else Right(i)
  )
  .doOnNext(either => either.map( i => println(s"Processing $i") ))
  .foreachL(either => either.map( i => println(s"Finished $i") ))
```

But `either => either.map(...)` in every step in not cool.

What is the better way to handle errors?

Comment: The exception is not really "thrown". It's sent through on the error channel as part of Observable's design for errors. Why do you not like it? The fact that you don't want to deal with it at every step is a hint that it should be done like the first example.

Comment: As @AlvaroCarrasco said, the `Exception` is never thrown and your first example is using `Observable`s as they are ment to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collect` if you only care about the right result, e.g.

```
val logError = {
  case Right(_) => Task.unit
  case Left(i) => Task.delay(println(s"An error occured $i"))
}

Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1,2,3))
  .map( i =>
    if (i == 2) Left("Wrong i")
    else Right(i)
  )
  .doOnNext(logError)
  .collect {
    case Right(value) => value
  }
  .foreachL(i => println(i))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to [drop](https://monix.io/docs/3x/reactive/observable.html#dropping-failed-elements) the bad element, you can do it this way.

```
Observable.fromIterable(1 to 3)
      .mapEval(p => { if(i == 2) Task.raiseError(new Exception) 
                      else Task.now(i)
                    }.attempt )
      .collect { case Right(v) => v }
      .foreachL(println)
      .runToFuture

/*
1
3
*/
```

Basically keep using Task and `attempt` to turn the Task composition into Task[Either].